# Python test if string matches a template value

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to iterate through a list of strings, keeping only those that match a naming template I have specified. I want to accept any list entry that matches the template exactly, other than having an integer in a variable `<SCENARIO>` field.

The check needs to be general. Specifically, the string structure could change such that there is no guarantee `<SCENARIO>` always shows up at character X (to use list comprehensions, for example).

The code below shows an approach that works using `split`, but there must be a better way to make this string comparison. Could I use regular expressions here?

```
template = 'name_is_here_<SCENARIO>_20131204.txt'

testList = ['name_is_here_100_20131204.txt',        # should accept
            'name_is_here_100_20131204.txt.NEW',    # should reject
            'other_name.txt']                       # should reject

acceptList = []

for name in testList:
    print name
    acceptFlag = True
    splitTemplate = template.split('_')
    splitName = name.split('_')
    # if lengths do not match, name cannot possibly match template
    if len(splitTemplate) == len(splitName):
        print zip(splitTemplate, splitName)
        # compare records in the split
        for t, n in zip(splitTemplate, splitName):
            if t!=n and not t=='<SCENARIO>':
                #reject if any of the "other" fields are not identical
                #(would also check that '<SCENARIO>' field is numeric - not shown here)
                print 'reject: ' + name
                acceptFlag = False
    else:
        acceptFlag = False

    # keep name if it passed checks
    if acceptFlag == True:
        acceptList.append(name)

print acceptList
# correctly prints --> ['name_is_here_100_20131204.txt']
```

Comment: Yes, one could use regex here. Do you have a regex so far?

Comment: @SimeonVisser - sorry, no regex yet. I know that regex exists, but I am not familiar with the implementation details. I wanted to make sure it was a worthwhile approach before going too far. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with the `re` module for regular expressions in Python:

```
import re

template = re.compile(r'^name_is_here_(\d+)_20131204.txt$')

testList = ['name_is_here_100_20131204.txt', #accepted
            'name_is_here_100_20131204.txt.NEW', #rejected!
            'name_is_here_aabs2352_20131204.txt', #rejected!
            'other_name.txt'] #rejected!

acceptList = [item for item in testList if template.match(item)]
```

Comment: This looks to be just about what I wanted. I guess the only problem is that I would like `template` to be variable, without needing to specifically enter the regex details. In other words, I would like to enter template in the format I specified, and have the code translate this into the regex statement automatically. I am sure there is a way to parse my template into the format you specified - I'll look into this next. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: I used a concatentation to build the generalized compile string: `feedNameRegex = '^' + feedName.replace('<SCENARIO>',r'(\d+)') + '$'`. Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: @Roberto Well, it seems good to me but you should test it in your context, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

This should do, I understand that name_is_here is just a placeholder for alphanumeric characters?

```
import re
testList = ['name_is_here_100_20131204.txt',        # should accept
            'name_is_here_100_20131204.txt.NEW',    # should reject
            'other_name.txt', 
            'name_is_44ere_100_20131204.txt',
            'name_is_here_100_2013120499.txt', 
            'name_is_here_100_something_2013120499.txt',
            'name_is_here_100_something_20131204.txt']  


def find(scenario):
    begin  = '[a-z_]+100_' # any combinations of chars and underscores followd by 100
    end = '_[0-9]{8}.txt$' #exactly eight digits followed by .txt at the end
    pattern = re.compile("".join([begin,scenario,end]))
    result = []
    for word in testList:
        if pattern.match(word):
            result.append(word)

    return result

find('something') # returns ['name_is_here_100_something_20131204.txt']
```

EDIT: scenario in separate variable, regex now only matches characters followed by 100, then scenarion, then eight digits followed by .txt.

Comment: This may be too general. I do not think this guarantees identical naming everywhere outside the required variable portion. For example `name_is_44ere_100_20131204.txt` would pass.

Comment: Ok, so name_is_here should only be letters separated by underscore. What part would you like to hold in variable? <SCENARIO>? Name_is_here_100 is going to be a constant string? Number of digits after scenario is going to be fixed? You can create regular expression from variable if you need to.